# Sumproduct a subarray in a separate closed worksheet

Tags: excel

I have two worksheets; I need to pull the "pounds shipped" for every day into worksheet two, which I obtain from worksheet one.  The number is the sum of all the pounds shipped for all the orders that happen every day.  I used this formula to get the correct answer:

=SUMIF('[Worksheet One]'!$C:$C, A2, '[Worksheet One]'!$AA$AA)

But because it's sumif and not sumproduct it won't update when worksheet one is closed.
Column C is the date, A2 is the date on worksheet two, and column AA is the pounds shipped.

I've tried using a SUMPRODUCT( INDEX( SMALL( IF( ROW() - ROW(), ROWS())))) formula but either it doesn't work or I couldn't get the right format.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to translate a `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` to a `SUMPRODUCT` formula, you have to use `--()` around the comparison test. That will convert TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0

So, from your formula of

```
=SUMIF('[Worksheet One]'!$C:$C, A2, '[Worksheet One]'!$AA$AA)
```

we would end up with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[Worksheet One]'!$C:$C = A2), '[Worksheet One]'!$AA$AA)
```

---

another example with SUMIFS,

```
=SUMIFS('[Wrksht1]'!$AA$AA,'[Wrksht1]'!$C:$C, A2,'[Wrksht1]'!$Q:$Q, B2)
```

would become

```
=SUMIFS('[Wrksht1]'!$AA$AA,--('[Wrksht1]'!$C:$C=A2),--('[Wrksht1]'!$Q:$Q=B2))
```

Comment: Side note, the -- is used to convert anything to a number, such as --"15", because it takes the double negative of a number.  The first time it will also attempted conversion, so you get -(-"15")=-(-15)=15.  It is similar to adding a +0, as they both leave the number unchanged, but require excel to convert.

Comment: It gave me a blank value for some reason.

Comment: note the conversion of the comparison from 2 parameters (`'[Worksheet One]'!$C:$C, A2`) to just 1, replacing the comma with an equals sign (`--('[Worksheet One]'!$C:$C = A2)`)

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--('[Q SHIP LIST III.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$C = A2), '[Q SHIP LIST III.xlsx]Sheet1'!$AA:$AA)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the length of the ranges? Do sumproducts have to have defined lengths?

Comment: sumproduct doesn't *need* a specific length, but it will work faster with a set size so it doesn't try to calculate 1,048,576 values for each column

Comment: Any idea what might be causing the blank result then?

Comment: the only way I can get SUMPRODUCT to return nothing is by formatting: Either set the text color equal to to background color, or number formatting where something is omitted in the format (e.g. using **#,##0.0;** will make negative numbers disappear)